# Create php class and files from back-panel

Tags: php, file, class, yii

I am working in eCommerce Project and I am facing a big work flow to create and maintain categories in my system, I have oriented categories into classes and minimum 2 files per class (class is base ex: cars, bikes .. etc and the 2 other files whitch are displayed when User is registering item in that particular category and the another one is into a search), the class have same structure, same function just different params and different actions, what I am trying to do is to create back-panel from where I would be able to create and maintain those files.

Is there any way of creating classes and files except creating them from $string and write into file with "fopen".

Yii framework have somehow the same functionality which give you the opportunity to create controllers, models and views(classess) from back-panel.
Just for info i am using codeigniter.

Comment: Sounds like a horrible hack. VC is lost, and cockups will break a live website. I think you need to do some re-factoring instead - i doubt you really need to write new classes every time you want to add a category

Comment: Well, about live website your right but I wont do it into my live but into test or development version and then upload into the live. Its kindly hard to menage more then 30 or 50 classes multiply with 2 files per class from scratch.

Comment: Agreed that sounds difficult to manage, apply DRY principle -  one single Category class that takes arguments to modify its behavior would be my suggestion.

Comment: Follow user574632's suggestion. You usually want classes based on types and not on singular entities. Those are meant to be instances of the type based classes.
Also keep in mind that many frameworks that use scaffolding are very difficult to maintain and extend (if the framework doesnt already manages this perfectly)

Comment: I totally understood what is your point and somehow your right and I'll have to check if this can be my solution, because in my case I have different classes with different files(x2), the only similarity is class structure. I know there is a way of fixing this from db but It will be another framework and this is the reason I chose to play with classes.

Comment: If you are using Codeigniter why do you add Yii as a tag?

Comment: @crafter Yii has somehow this feature, thats why I tagged yii, I thought my someone knows how its works.